# Apache Zeppelin dynamic user account creation

Tags: shiro, apache-zeppelin

I've been searching on how to create user account dynamically at runtime with `Zeppelin`.
Looking at the document about shiro.ini, following statements exist.

**`[users]`**
The `[users]` section allows you to define a static set of user accounts. This is mostly useful in environments with a very small number of user accounts or where user accounts don’t need to be created dynamically at runtime. Here’s an example:

```
[users]
admin = secret
lonestarr = vespa, goodguy, schwartz
darkhelmet = ludicrousspeed, badguy, schwartz
```

So I know this is for creating accounts before starting `Zeppelin`.
But, I can't find how to create a account dynamically at runtime.
No such a function in `Zeppelin`?

Thanks.

Comment: Creating users is outside the scope of Shiro.  That said, it is definitely possible, other applications/libs have done this.  Typically though, users stored in an external realm (i.e. something like LDAP) are managed through some other IT process.

I'm not familiar enough with Zeppelin to know if it provides user management.